# GridView after Filter dont want to display previous View (without filter)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with Filter data in GridView. I want to Exclude some variables and if i want back to previous GridView it dont want to show all values. Have you any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
//i check if there is a value in textbox that filter me a Grid
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(whatToFilter))
    {
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = " Some_Column NOT LIKE '%" + TextUnFiltrAgg.Value + "%'";
        AggregateGridView.DataSource = dt;
        AggregateGridView.DataBind();
        txtCountNumRows.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0}", dt.DefaultView.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        DataTable dtSession = (DataTable)Session["DataTable"];
        AggregateGridView.DataSource = dtSession;
        AggregateGridView.DataBind();
        txtCountNumRows.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0}", dt.Rows.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

When you don't want to filter then just clear the value of textbox TextUnFiltrAgg.

Thanx.

Comment: It almost works on "`Some_column LIKE '%%'`" but not on "`Some_column 
NOT LIKE '%%`'"  It exclude me rows where value is '%%' so all values..